# spring-authorization-server custom form login demo sample throws NPE when using authorization_code grant type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to run the demo-samples of **spring-oauth2-authorization-server** customized form based login. When using the authorization_code as grant type, after entering credentials on the login page I get NullPointerException in the **DefaultErrorController**.

Here is the stack trace from **DefaultErrorController**:

```
2023-06-24T14:09:53.415+05:30 ERROR 8240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "errorMessage" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "errorMessage" is null
    at com.sample.authservice.controller.DefaultErrorController.handleError(DefaultErrorController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
```

Here is my code:

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/logged-out")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = Jwks.generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
}
```

**DefaultSecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/assets/**", "/webjars/**", "/login").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
//                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
                .formLogin(formLogin ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                        oauth2Login
                                .loginPage("/login")
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**DefaultErrorController**

```
@Controller
public class DefaultErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorMessage(request);
        if (errorMessage.startsWith("[access_denied]")) {
            model.addAttribute("errorTitle", "Access Denied");
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "You have denied access.");
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("errorTitle", "Error");
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        }
        return "error";
    }

    private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I omitted the login pages as they are exactly same from the samples.

**Environment Details:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Tools: Maven, JDK 17.0.4, IntelliJ Idea
- Spring Boot version: 3.1.1
- Spring-Oauth2-Authorization-Server Version: 1.1.1

Using postman I tried to execute the OAUTH2 authorization_code flow. The login page [login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZhPF.png) pops up like this and after entering the credentials, the Error page comes up like this [Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOZz0.png)

I tried to debug the code and observed that

```
return (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

the attribute is not being set in the HttpServletRequest. Is that due to a missing config due to which servlet context is not setting up?

Am I missing something in my configuration?

**Update:**

I tried to put debugger at line

```
return (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

inside DefaultErrorController. It gives this error:

```
((ApplicationHttpRequest)((StrictFirewalledRequest)((Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper)((ResourceUrlEncodingRequestWrapper)request).request).request).request).mapping = Cannot cast 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequestAwareWrapper' to 'org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest'
```

Any insights?

Edit:
The client_id and client_secret are present in the access_token response. Here is the screenshot of the [access_token response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwvL9.png)

Comment: This error does not occur for me in the demo-sample in the official repo. Can you please provide steps to reproduce using the demo-sample in the repo (not your custom one)? Otherwise, can you please provide trace logs (`logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`) to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg, please take a look the [trace-logs](https://file.io/30pYuoOfuxhG). Also, I will try to re-clone the sample try to run it once again. When I ran the trace, I see that it fails for first time when I ask for token and if I ask for token again I'm able to get it. Hopefully trace logs will help. Thanks

Comment: That link seems broken and I cannot view the logs. Please edit the question and post them here.

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg I cannot share the trace-logs by editing the question. There are lot of logs. I'm sharing it once again: [TRACE_LOGS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_XvrZHWa2k2s1ObV9_UJRLuXjYcSBYS5/view?usp=drive_link) If it asks for permission, please request I will provide the access.

Comment: Try permitting the `/error` route in your `DefaultSecurityConfig` for testing. You're getting an error but it's not clear what is causing it. Opening up the error page will help you see that.

Comment: I permitted `/error` route in the `DefaultSecurityConfig`. I'm able to get the access_token now. It is a bit strange to find the cause. Here are the [Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTFoJPP3oUJ19ZZOavXqEsN24hdSDyuq/view?usp=drive_link) after permitting the `/error` route.

Comment: Permitting `/error` is not really the solution to the problem, only a debugging step used to help you find the problem. It's still not clear to me what the error actually is since the logs are all mixed with async requests to load assets on the login page. You have a number of `Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession...` entries in the log. Are you launching the flow using localhost:8080 to redirect to localhost:9000? That will cause cookies to clash between the two Spring Boot apps and may cause this issue.

Comment: I'm launching the flow using Postman. Auth server runs on port 9000. I have provided all the required endpoints starting with example `http://127.0.01:9000/authorize` in Postman. Can you share some debug points?  I will try to debug the code.

Comment: Apart from these, I can see client_id and secret in the access_token response. Can you explain me why is that? The client_id and secret are sensitive details which should not be included in access_token. How can I hide this sensitive info?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not able to see what you're seeing and have never seen what you're describing.

Comment: I have edited the question and added link to the screenshot of what I'm trying to say in the above comment. Note that I have not modified anything in the code and directly running from the samples.

Comment: The screenshot you added is of the Postman UI. That is not the access token response parameters. The client secret is never included in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine now. I shifted to new development environment and seems like there was issue with the old development environment. Thanks for clarification on the points.